# Stack Apps Ellipse displaying as &hellip; in apps and scripts tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, stackapps, encoding

In Stack Apps [apps tab](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps) and [scripts tab](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) post's tool tip end, the ellipses (three dots) is not rendering properly, it displays as `&hellip;` *(horizontal ellipse)* instead of the ellipses.

In active, hot, week and month tab posts the ellipses are rendering correctly.

[image: Horizontal Ellipse showing as …]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup - it only shows for captions over 200 characters, but is unquestionably wrong. This has been fixed in the source, so: next deploy.

Comment: Yeah, It's fixed in the `rev 2016.1.22.3206 `.